# Input fields don't work in absolute positioning

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am making a small web app that only appears when the user is logged in. The div is in absolute positioning so it stays at the top of the page.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="open">
    <div id="outerwrapper">
        <div id="holder">
            <button id="titlebar">Open</button>
        </div>

        <div id="wrapper">
            <form>
                <select id="choice">
                    <option value="1">Background Color</option>
                    <option value="2">Menu/Header Colors</option>
                    <option value="3">Fonts</option>
                    <option value="4">Header Font</option>
                    <option value="5">Drag-and-Drop</option>
                </select>
            </form>

            <form>
                <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="colors, font faces, etc"/>
            </form>
            <button id="apply">Apply</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, when the div is formatted as `position: absolute`, the input fields don't work. The dropdown menu, text input, and button don't work.

Is there a way to make the div stay at the top of the page and still be able to use the dropdown selection, text input, and the button?

Comment: We need CSS as well. The CSS has to be known in order to resolve styling (CSS) and mark up (HTML) Better yet, a demo on jsFiddle would be gr8 if possible.

Comment: @zer00ne here's [a pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNxyJX) and the site where it'll be integrated apizzimenti.blogspot.com

Comment: @apizzimeni, I hope you didn't run off thinking that changing z-index fixes it. Please look at my answer and learn what really broke your code.

Comment: @zer00ne I didn't, I read your response. For the purpose of my demo, my solution worked, and I'm trying your solution out too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two `position` properties on on element. `#open` has `absolute` and `fixed`. I got rid of absolute and left `fixed` now it works.

### ORIGINAL CSS

```
#open
font-family: $mainfont
position: absolute; \\2 positions is not good
position: fixed;
width: 100%
```

### NEW CSS

```
#open
font-family: $mainfont
top: 0px;      \\ I added this
position: fixed; \\ I deleted position: absolute and kept fixed
width: 100%
z-index: 1  \\ You added the z-index: 1 which isn't that necessary since the rest of your elements are static.
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the button tag has no name value and no submit?

So you could try

```
<button type="submit" id="apply" name="apply" value="insert or submit">Submit</button>
```

Also you need the name="" attribute in the select tag in the form so

```
 <form>
            <select id="choice" name="apply">
                <option value="1">Background Color</option>
                <option value="2">Menu/Header Colors</option>
                <option value="3">Fonts</option>
                <option value="4">Header Font</option>
                <option value="5">Drag-and-Drop</option>
            </select>
        </form>
```

You should also have the input like

```
<input id="input" name="input" type="text" placeholder="colors, font faces, etc"/>
```

I may just be giving you info that I use to submit the data in the dropdown to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the z-index of the div so it takes precedence over other elements on the page. This seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: Although z-index could be the culprit, it's unlikely since your #open couldn't function in or out of the flow having two position properties vying for control.